# How can I suggest ideas to the "Ubuntu for phones" project?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, contributing, ubuntu-phone

Are feature requests and ideas welcome? To whom should I address them to?

Answer (score 0):

Currently ubuntu phone is being developed inside the closed doors of canonical, so the community have no access to it. BTW you can send ideas directly to ubuntu mobile team or post it in brainstorm.ubuntucom

Comment: Thanks! that what I need, only to say some offers, not giving codes ^^ . Can you give me a link to ubuntu mobile team?

Comment: Yes: gomobile@ubuntu.com